# Liferay portal logging out on refresh when AJAX call is waiting for response

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, liferay, session-timeout

I have this weird issue where my Liferay portal logs out when I try to refresh the page or go to some other page the same application when there is an AJAX call waiting for response.

What might be the cause for this?

Answer (score 0):

Some things that come to my mind:

- You're using mixed https/http operations (e.g. logged in on https, doing ajax on http without the session cookie, getting a new one that's not authenticated
- Your Ajax call goes to a different domain name/IP, so that it doesn't contain the session cookie, thus is not logged in
- Your Ajax call contains some ;jsessionid=2345 URL content, overriding session cookies, starting a new session
- Some filter/intrusion detection false-positives on the request and terminates the session
- Your backend code explicitly logs out the user.

This is in rough order of diminishing returns.

It might be good to use a network monitor and inspect the requests/responses. Use Firebug or the similar tools for any other browser.